# wxPython How to make a text input widget

Tags: python, wxpython

```
import wx

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame=Frame()
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"Frame",size(600,600))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        button=wx.Button(panel,label="ClickMe",pos=(50,50),size=(100,100))
        self.bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.username, button)


    def username(self,event):
        dlg=TextEntryDialog(None,"What is you name","TxtEntryDialog","UserName")
        if dlg.ShowModal()=wx.ID_OK:
            UserName=dlg.GetValue()
```

ok, what I am trying to do, is to replace the `TextEntryDialog`, with something that does not pop up after a button is clicked, but stays there in the frame, as for example the search bar on google.... is that event possible?

P.S there may be bugs in the program...but it is just to give an idea

Comment: maybe you can use [wx.TextCtrl](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextCtrl-class.html). I highly recommend to download wxPython Demo and play with it. Then you will see what widgets are available and how to use them. also [this](http://labs.beatcraft.com/en/index.php?Python%20%2F%20Windows%20GUI%20programming%20with%20wxPython) may help.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!I will check out wxPython Demo ASAP!!!

Answer (score 0):

You want the wx.TextCtrl. It is the go-to widget for entering text. There are a few others, such as StyledText, but I have rarely needed those. If you need a control for searching, you should check out the SearchCtrl widget.

I second @otterb's suggestion of using the wxPython demo. It will help you learn about the vast majority of available widgets.